# router.post('/', controller) vs router.route('/').get(controller)

Tags: node.js, rest, express, routes

What's the difference between writing routes:

```
//in this style
router.route('admin').get(getAllAdminsController).post(createAdminController)
```

and this type of writing:

```
router.get('admin', getallAdminsController);
router.post('admin', createAdminController);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no difference in terms of functionality. The first style is called chained route, and the purpose of it based on the documentation is:

> Because the path is specified at a single location, creating modular routes is helpful, as is reducing redundancy and typos

From: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#app-route